# How do I check for a default profile pic with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I’m currently trying to find a way to block commands on my bot if the sender has a default profile picture, how would I code this?

Comment: One way to improve is to check the profile pictures of all discord users and see the difference between the ones with the default and ones without the default pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is equivalent to checking if the [`avatar_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.avatar_url) equals [`default_avatar_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.default_avatar_url) for the author.  We can package that in a [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) pretty easily:

```
has_avatar = commands.check(lambda ctx: ctx.avatar_url != ctx.author.default_avatar_url)

@has_avatar
@bot.command()
def some_command(ctx):
    await cts.send("You have set your avatar")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @Mottly24 remember to mark this as the best answer.